# Multiple microsites will login as one

Tags: php, session, authentication, web, codeigniter-3

I have multiple microsites:

```
https://www.samplesite.com
https://subdomain2.samplesite.com
https://subdomain3.samplesite.com
https://subdomain4.samplesite.com
https://subdomain5.samplesite.com
```

Once I login to one of these, it should also automatically create a logged session for other microsites just like GOOGLE.

How can I  do this? Any ideas?

As I know, session is individually created for each domains and is certainly not readable for other domains.

P.S. I am using codeigniter as framework.

Comment: Use cookies and store the cookies id and tacking id in same Database and in each website check through same database for existence. Make everything is hashed.

Comment: Also you can implement OAuth server or use some kind of JWT tokens to authenticate users

Answer (score 0):

You should be searching the keyword "Single Sign-On". There are many ways to do it. But basically, you'd need:

1. A broker server for centralized login service. This server would allow user to login (through OAuth or whatever mean) and hold session information. And provide ways for other website (i.e. application) to retrieve that session information.
2. Adapt your websites (i.e. application) to use the broker server's session. Probably with mixed backend php and frontend js work.

A quick search for PHP library yield this result:

https://github.com/legalthings/sso

There are probably other libraries that can do the same trick.